# Some keyboard character stop working randomly

Tags: keyboard, parrotsec

OS: Parrot 5.0 using KDE plasma version 5.20.5

Laptop: Thinkpad x1 yoga 2nd gen

Keyword that are not working sometimes.

- Spacebar, B, N, Left arrow, Right arrow.

Those are the keys that I noticed. Usually all of those keys stopped working simultaneously.

Once the key stopped working, it will be okay again after some random minutes and the cycle repeats.

Anyone know what might caused this and a way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this reproducible under Windows?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have windows installed

Comment: I didn't ask to know whether you have or don't have Windows installed. I asked you to test this issue under Windows. That's the only way to be sure it's not a HW issue. This is free to test for 90 days: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise